# Contar Curtidas Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase

Então estou com um projeto aqui de um appblog, 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso de ajuda agora pra conseguir contar as curtidas.

```
    mDatabaseLike = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes");


  }
        });

        viewHolder.mLikeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                mProcessLike = true;


                    mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                              if (mProcessLike ){

                                    if(dataSnapshot.child(post_key).hasChild(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())){

                                        mDatabaseLike.child(post_key).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();
                                        mProcessLike = false;
                                    } else {

                                         mDatabaseLike.child(post_key).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue("RandomValue");
                                        mProcessLike = false;
                                    }

                        }}

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                }
        });

    }
};
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

http://pastebin.com/JKCa4feS

**RESOLVIDO**

```
    mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Log.e(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child(post_key)),dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + "");

            for (DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //Log.e(String.valueOf(snap.child(currentUserId).toString()),snap.getChildrenCount() + "");
                mCurtidas.setText(dataSnapshot.child(currentUserId).getChildrenCount() + "");

            }}
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: Que problema esta tendo?

Comment: Problema nenhum, eu não sei como contar as curtidas, o códiogo ta tudo certo, mais não tem nenhuma linha sobre como contar as curtidas...

Comment: Você vai precisar usar um listener, assim que abrir a activity pra saber se ja foi curtido.

Caso sim, o click retirar, caso não, curte.

No seu print parece que esta funcionando.

Se você esta em duvida sobre a quantidade de curtidas. Você só precisa pegar o "ramo" Likes e fazer um size();

Comment: ok, a parte do botão ta certo, já está clicável.

Comment: Você tem noção de como eu faço isso de modo que conte a .child do firebase?

Comment: Você deve ter uma classe, que encapsula o conteudo do post do blog.
Adiciona uma variavel, que conta os likes. Pode ser um list ou um int mesmo.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

Answer (score 0):

Você deve ter uma classe, que encapsula o conteúdo do post do blog.
Adiciona uma variavel, que conta os likes. Pode ser um list ou um int mesmo.
No listener do database, você captura o conteúdo que ta no banco.

```
   // Read from the database
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    // This method is called once with the initial value and again
    // whenever data at this location is updated.
    SuaClasse  class = dataSnapshot.getValue(SuaClass.class);

    }

    @Override
     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
    // Failed to read value
    Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
   }
  });
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/